# How to remove CSV headers and keep columns seperate using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, header, export

I'm trying to split a CSV in to 2 based on the values in the first column. The newly created CSVs cannot have a column name and this is where the problem arises. When I remove the headers, all the values go into the first column.

In order to split the CSV based on the first column value I've had to assign headers. The 2 new files are created successfully with the correct values, however my final step is to remove the headers as the application used to process the CSV will not accept column names.

Once I've removed the headers, all the values are no longer separated by the comma and as a result are all in the first column. How can I get around this?

```
if (!(Test-Path X:)) {
    $net = New-Object -comobject Wscript.Network
    $net.MapNetworkDrive("X:","**Path**")
}

$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "**Path**"  | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-10) -and
    $_.Name -like '*.CSV*'
}

if ($file) {
    $filename = $file.FullName
    $date = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    $ExportPathJUO = "**Path**$date"
    $ExportPathWDA = "**Path**$date"

    ##Create Seperate Files in Staging Folder
    $csv = Import-Csv $filename -Header A,B,C,D,E,F,G
    $IDS = $csv | select -ExpandProperty A -Unique
    foreach ($ID in $IDS) {
        $csv | where {
            $_.A -like '*0000009*'
        } | Export-Csv $ExportPathJUO -NoTypeInformation
    }
    foreach ($ID in $IDS) {
        $csv | where {
            $_.A -like '*0000007*'
        } | Export-Csv $ExportPathWDA -NoTypeInformation
    }

    ##Remove Headers
    (Get-content $ExportPathJUO) |
        select -Skip 1 |
        Out-File -FilePath $ExportPathJUO -Force
    (Get-content $ExportPathWDA) |
        select -Skip 1 |
        Out-File -FilePath $ExportPathWDA -Force 
}
```

Comment: You treat the outcome of your Get-ChildItem `$file` as a single item instead of a possible array better iterated with a foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `*-Csv` cmdlets if you don't have/want headers in your CSV. What you want can be done like this:

```
foreach (line in Get-Content $filename) {
    $a = $line.Split(',')[0]
    switch -wildcard ($a) {
        '*0000007*' { $line | Add-Content $ExportPathWDA }
        '*0000009*' { $line | Add-Content $ExportPathJUO }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this will work this case, it won't work where one of the input values has an escaped comma in it.

Comment: @MartinBrown True. But I usually try to avoid over-engineering a solution.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Just thought I'd mention it because I've spent way too many hours fixing that bug in multiple systems over my career. As long as people are aware of the issue that's fine.